# Neo4j Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/neo4j/cypher/javacompat/ExecutionEngine on unmanaged extensions

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to use an unmanaged extension which uses 2.1.2 neo4j.version
on a neo4j server (version CE 3.5.11 Cypher version: CYPHER 3.5).

The neo4j server starts properly but when I invoke the Rest Service provided by that unmanaged extension via Postman I get the following error

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/neo4j/cypher/javacompat/ExecutionEngine
```

the extension is installed via the following pom :

```
<properties>
    <neo4j.version>2.1.2</neo4j.version>
</properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>server-api</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-shell</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-shell</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

locally the extension works well all unit tests succeed.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `<neo4j.version>` to `3.5.11`, to be compatible with the neo4j server version.

If necessary, you may also need to fix the extension so that it will build and work correctly, since version `2.1.2` is extremely old.

Comment: Thank you very much cybersam. I followed your hint and It works like a charm.